# Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to implement a application using Spring (+JPA) and Hibernate using anotations.

I recentrly added the JPA part. Since then i get:

```
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
```

Error. 
I also get following warnings:

```
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
```

I'm not sure if these two things are related but I thought I would ad the warnings.

Hereis my application-context.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <!-- Package needed to be scanned for annotation -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.redast"/>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.redast"/>
    <!-- Use annotation for configuration-->
    <!--<context:annotation-config/>-->
    <context:spring-configured/>


    <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
    <bean name="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/redast" />
        <property name="username" value="xxxxxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxxxxx" />
    </bean>




    <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
    <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.redast.model</value>
                <value>com.redast.service</value>
                <value>com.redast.dao</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    <!--        <property name="persistenceUnitPostProcessors">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.data.jpa.support.ClasspathScanningPersistenceUnitPostProcessor">
                    <constructor-arg value="com.redast" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>-->

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

    </bean>

    <!-- Enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

    <!-- Transaction Manager is defined -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="SessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    <bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    </bean>
    -->

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
          class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

I am rather new to Spring and hibernate, so my .xml file might well be arrornous. (Difficult for me to, from looking at tutorials and different sources, what exactly it is I need and what not.)

Here one of my DAOs

```
import com.redast.model.Announcement;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface AnnouncementDAO extends JpaRepository<Announcement, Long>{

}
```

And here the full error:

```
Warnung:   Ignore WEB-INF/sun-web.xml in archive /C:/Ben/NetBeansProjects/redast/target/redast-1.0-SNAPSHOT/, as WLS counterpart runtime xml WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml is present in the same archive.
Information:   14:14:05.019 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Information:   14:14:05.032 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
Information:   14:14:05.032 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
Information:   14:14:05.053 [admin-listener(2)] INFO  o.s.d.j.r.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension - Activating CDI extension for Spring Data JPA repositories.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] protected org.springframework.data.repository.cdi.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
WARN:   WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.
Information:   14:14:05.431 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.ProcessDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.437 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.AssetFragmentDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.463 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.RoleDAOImpl' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.484 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.FragmentValueDefDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.489 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.FragmentDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.490 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.ProcessNodeDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.494 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.AnnouncementDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.499 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.AssetDAO' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Information:   14:14:05.506 [admin-listener(2)] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.CdiRepositoryExtensionSupport - Discovered repository type 'com.redast.dao.UserDAOImpl' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
Schwerwiegend:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI definition failure:Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:271)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ExtensionObserverMethodImpl.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:258)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:237)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:174)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:133)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:107)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:54)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDefinitionContainerEvent.java:42)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.fire(AfterBeanDiscoveryImpl.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.deployBeans(WeldStartup.java:396)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:496)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Unable to resolve a bean for 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Default(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()].
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.createRepositoryBean(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension.afterBeanDiscovery(JpaRepositoryExtension.java:94)...
```

Thanks for your effort

Comment: Think your `sessionFactory` should start with a lowercase `s` in the bean id.

Comment: This isn't spring related but has everything to do with CDI. Rename (or remove) your `persistence.xml` and ify ou have also your `beans.xml` the latter triggers CDI to be enabled and first might instruct glassfish to bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory` and proces annotations which leads to problems because you want Spring to do this.

Comment: Hi, Deinum. 
I actually had a beans.xml. (some tutorial told me to add an empty beans.xml) this actually fixed the problem described above. But unveiled a new one: `creating bean with name 'AnnouncementService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;... Could not autowire field: private com.redast.dao.AnnouncementDAO ..NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [AnnouncementDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: @M.Deinum would you rephrase your comment as answer? since it did solfe the initial problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Judging from the stacktrace you have CDI interfering/competing with Spring. CDI is enabled when you have a `beans.xml` in your application. Remove this to disable CDI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have two containers: CDI and Spring container trying to own the JPA beans.

You can include/exclude packages in CDI beans.xml or choose CDI Version > 1.1 @Vetoed annotations or other restrictions to let CDI know that it should not scan and own any of JPA repos/beans by the CDI container and Spring container has the ownership for these JPA entityManager and factory beans.

The other option is to go CDI route and take over entityManager creation that Spring can use via the CDI extension.

This problem explains what exactly is happening in these cases: [JBoss EAP 7.1 Spring-Data-JPA CDI Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756761/jboss-eap-7-1-spring-data-jpa-cdi-extension)

Comment: a little late :-) but may be helpful to others who come here